# Applying Kalman Filter to a List of Data with error

Tags: kalman-filter

First of all, this is not a homework or project or anything that I need to complete for my own benefit.

I have an object located at (3m, 2m)
I've read the position of this object from a device 16 times and I have a list like this:

---

### No  |   x   |   y   |  Error

R1  |  3,11 |  2.22 |  sqrt((2.22  -  2)^2 + (3.11 - 3)^2)

R2  |  3.18 |  2.11 |  sqrt((2.11  -  2)^2 + (3.18 - 3)^2)

R3  |  3.15 |  2.13 |  sqrt((2.13  -  2)^2 + (3.15 - 3)^2)

........

R16 |  3.16 |  2.16 |  sqrt((2.16  -  2)^2 + (3.16 - 3)^2)

The goal is to apply Kalman Filtering to reduce Average error

Average = (Error_1 + Error_2 + Error_3 + ...... + Error_16) / 16

Can u give me an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem can be formed like this:

Form an array of meazurement with error: [Error_1, Error_2, Error_3, ..... Error_16]

Then calculate standard deviation of these numbers.
[how to calculate](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)
[/ calculate online](http://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html)

R variable of Kalman Filter is standard deviation of the list

z variable of Kalman Filter is the array we formed above from errorz.

Since this is a linear problem and consist of single numbers, we can assign 1 or 0 to other Kalman Filter variables.

Then, run Kalman Filter algorithm and we will see that values of this array will converge to the real.

An example that I tried to code can be seen and tested from this link: [OctaveOnline](https://octave-online.net/bucket~G7fCQseUa2fuU3ztpPQwZP)